# Capture image from camera and save to SD card

Tags: android

I am trying to capture image and then save it into the SDCard .But the camera is getting on but the image is not saving on the location and even it is not creating the folder.Please check the below code to on the camera capture a image and then save it .

```
public class TakePicture extends Activity {
int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_picture);

    //here,we are making a folder named picFolder to store pics taken by the camera using this application
        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/"; 
        File newdir = new File(dir); 
        newdir.mkdirs();

        Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here,counter will be incremented each time,and the picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg and likewise.

            String file = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            File newfile = new File(file);
            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {}       

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
            Log.d("data-----",data.toString());


        }else{
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pics Not Saved ");
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you specified Permissions to Access Sd Card i mean write to external storage..?

Comment: google it ...so many answers available

Comment: @SoftwareSainath i have done in the manifest file i have addes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Just Print requestCode and responseCode in onActivityResult and observer what values you are getting

Comment: @SoftwareSainath requestCode is 0 and the response code is -1

Comment: Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
Try Changing This Line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5991757/1696704 and this link

Comment: i have done the same changes now it's working fine for me .Thanks alot @SoftwareSainath

Comment: Its ok Go Ahead All The Best!!!!! For Your Work

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but wouldn'nt it be easier to use the stock camera application? You can access it using this code in your activity:

```
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.capture);

                Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_button);
                capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // We use the stock camera app to take a photo
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri imagePath = getImageUri();

                    doSomething();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Get the uri of the captured file
             * @return A Uri which path is the path of an image file, stored on the dcim folder
             */
            private Uri getImageUri() {
                // Store image in dcim
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM", CAPTURE_TITLE);
                Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                return imgUri;
            }
```

Comment: Thank You, Working Fine.